# How to reverse calculate and find rate before tax?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Rate After TAX Formula:

```
Sale Rate: 100
Discount 1: 10% value = 100 * 10 / 100 = 10, 100 - 10 = 90
Discount 2: 5% value = 90 * 5 / 100 = 4.5, 90 - 4.5 = 85.5
Net Rate: 85.5
Tax: 18
Rate After Tax: 85.50 * 18 / 100 = 15.39, 85.50 + 15.39 = 100.89
Answer: 100.89
```

Now, How can I reverse calculate it and find rate before tax?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain the setup?  What are the discounts and why are there two of them?

Comment: In accounting, we sometimes require multiple discounts. Discount 1 and 2 is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Since the discounts are effectively multiplying the rate by $0.9$ and $0.95$ respectively and adding tax is multiplying with $1.18$: $100\times0.9\times0.95\times1.18 = 100.89$.

So to calculate reversely you divide by the factors instead. $100.89 / (1.18\times0.9\times0.95)=100.0$. If you want to calculate the net rate you just divide by the tax factor: $100.89/1.18 = 85.5$.

Comment: Sir discount can be changed. Discount is dynamic variable.

Comment: @ShahRushabh Of course, you have to adjust the factors accordingly. To adjust for a discount of $R\%$ is the same as multiplying with a factor $(1-R/100)$ (eg a $10\%$ discount means multiplying with $0.9=(1-10/100)$ and a $5\%$ discount means multiplying with $0.95 = (1-5/100)$.)